# How can I find which parish a village in Poland belonged to?

Tags: poland, church-records

Someone on Facebook just helped me find immigration records for the [Vannoske](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/8088/where-did-the-vannoskes-come-from) family which point to [Rudnicze, Poland](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rudnicze) as their place of origin. How can I figure out which parish that village belonged to?

Answer (score 2):

Not to confuse you further, but are you sure you have the right village? There is another place of the same name, also in Wielkopolska - it currently belongs to 'Parafia św. Andrzeja Boboli w Poznaniu' (Parish of St. Andrew Bobola in Poznań).

Anyway, I'd opt for emailing the 'suspected' parish - the priests should know the local history and are quite likely to be able to point you to where the records are stored (which in either case is most likely the Archdiocesan Archive in Poznań). For the parish in south Poznan (which used to be in Komorniki): http://www.parafiajunikowo.archpoznan.pl/kontakt/ For one likely to cover Rudnicze near Wągrowiec, try the parish in Wągrowiec http://wagrowiec.paulini.pl/?page_id=65

Comment: No, I don't know. Do you know which one this is for: http://www.szukajwarchiwach.pl/92/86/0/4/146?q=Rudnicze+XSKANro:t&wynik=1&rpp=15&page=1#tabSkany

Comment: I asked about that Seelenliste form the Polish archives because I found the family in there.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the cover of the book says Wongrowiec.

Comment: It most definitely does.

Answer (score 1):

In many cases, identifying the name or extent of a parish will depend on the religious denomination and the time period. A parish may also have some civil scope (as in Louisiana).

I think in this case we can assume you mean the Roman Catholic parish, instead of the Lutheran parish, and that the time period is around 1900.

[Kartenmeister](http://www.kartenmeister.com/preview/databaseuwe.asp) has 2 entries for Rudnicze:

- [Biberfeld](http://www.kartenmeister.com/preview/City.asp?CitNum=25421) - Catholic Parish: Wongrowitz 1905
- [Rudnitsch](http://www.kartenmeister.com/preview/City.asp?CitNum=25418) - Catholic Parish: Rogasen, Kreis Obornik 1905

Wongrowitz is now Wągrowiec; Rogasen is now Rogoźno

[The Google map link for Rudnitsch is wonky, but I've found this database generally reliable for its data]