# What are the names of these Polish villages?

Tags: palaeography, poland

I found a seelenliste of the [Wojnowski family](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/8088/where-did-the-vannoskes-come-from) which includes their places of birth. The only problem is that they were all born in different places (according to this) and some of the names are difficult to discern, especially for someone unfamiliar with the area.

Here's a picture. The last column is the place of birth. [Full image](http://www.szukajwarchiwach.pl/92/86/0/4/146/skan/full/dj_F3eF6JFDmw4q8LfIBNA)

[image]

The seelenliste is from [Rudnicze](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rudnicze). Here's what I've got so far:

- Joseph - Po*any (possibly Polany but it doesn't look like an l)
- Hedwig - Toniszewo
- Marianna - Bialy***
- Andreas - Pawlowo
- Michalina - Nowe

So I guess I need help with Joseph's and Marianna's places of birth.

Here's [a map](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Paw%C5%82owo+%C5%BBo%C5%84skie,+Poland/Toniszewo,+Polska/Nowe,+W%C4%85growiec+County,+Poland/Rudnicze,+Poland/%C5%81ekno,+Poland/@52.8582841,17.1326576,12z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m32!4m31!1m5!1m1!1s0x470388dadf740a2f:0x30407fd86da3977a!2m2!1d17.1762344!2d52.9090822!1m5!1m1!1s0x470388eca97d53d9:0x7e33ee98fae63928!2m2!1d17.1843479!2d52.8937774!1m5!1m1!1s0x4703883968e3b4d1:0x69829ba7adc8f164!2m2!1d17.1497301!2d52.8558025!1m5!1m1!1s0x470477ad1f8be127:0x8e623782d64e7d96!2m2!1d17.1076045!2d52.8148495!1m5!1m1!1s0x470387371ea1c11f:0x59b04914ad443a88!2m2!1d17.3048283!2d52.841136!3e0) of some of those villages near Rudnicze, including Lekno where Joseph and Hedwig might have been married, according to a possible match from the [Poznan Project](http://poznan-project.psnc.pl/).

Comment: It's a bit further away, but maybe Bialy Dwor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Seelenliste doesn't have an apparent creation date (in fact, there are several handwriting styles), but all the birthdates on the page are before 1870. To identify the placenames, one would need a contemporary list of placenames (i.e. the German placenames, as Rudnitze was then in the Prussian province of Posen).

The [list of subordinate objects for the former Kreis (county) of Wongrowitz](http://gov.genealogy.net/item/show/object_262357), contains the placenames

- Gollantsch or Gołańcz [looks like Gollancz, which could be a spelling variation]
- Tonischewo
- Bialybrod
- Pawlowo - but there are 2 of these: Pawlowo bei Gollantsch, Pawlowo bei Schokken
- Nowen

I think these match the placenames in the image. If any of the image placenames had not had a good correspondence, similar lists for neighboring Kreise could have been checked.

The referenced list has each of those placenames linked to their own page which includes modern map links.

Comment: The following link lists Bialybrod as an estate in Lekno which makes sense because that's where the parents were married. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kreis_Wongrowitz

Comment: There's also the possibility that the father Joseph had a previous marriage which occurred in Golancz.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the one for Joseph may be Poznan, a town near Rudnicze.  I think that third letter that looks like an "m" is actually a "z," and I don't think that's a "y" at the end.  I think the part coming down that looks like the tail of a "y" is actually part of that squiggly line that comes down from above.  I'm not 100% sure of this, but that's my best guess.  I hope that's helpful!

I don't know about the "Bialy..." one yet, but I'll have a look around and see if I can come up with a good guess.  Is it possible to put up an image that shows more of that same page?  Sometimes I can find other words that I do recognize and then compare the shapes of the letters to try and find a match to the letters of the unknown word, if that makes any sense.

The Bialy one is more difficult. It looks like the next letter after "y" is an "l." The only place I could find that kinda looks like the word on your page is Bialy Lug, but that's much further east. It's apparently in the Warsaw area, on the south side of that city. Do you think it's possible that it could be Bialy Lug?

Comment: The question contains a link to the full image, but everything else on that page was written by a different person.